# Background video not showing electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I'm creating an electron application who need to have a video in background, muted autoplaying loop video, but, I don't know why, when I'm adding the video, with html like this:

```
<video muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="./assets/background.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Or like this, with javascript and jquery:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        let video = $('<video />', {
            id: 'bkgvid',
        }).prop({
            muted: true,
            autoplay: true,
            loop: true,
        });
        $('<source />', {
            type: 'video/mp4', 
            src: '../assets/background.mp4'
        }).appendTo(video);
        video.appendTo($('body'));

    });

})(jQuery);
```

The video is adding in the dom,
but don't showing in the renderer, look:
[image: Screenshot of editor]

The path is good, the mp4 file exists, I don't know the problem.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
When i'm trying to add an image, It's showing, in the dom and in the sources, but the mp4 is not showed in the Sources:
[image: Sources tab]

At the beginning I was thinking It's cause the file size is 25.7Mo, but yesterday it was working fine..

Comment: If you go to the network tab in your inspector do you see it trying to load it in?

Comment: Where is your video file placed? `./assets/background.mp4` or `../assets/background.mp4`

Comment: Yeah, the background.mp4 is loaded in the Network tab, have a look: http://prntscr.com/sc951v

Comment: It's `./assets/background.mp4` I've seen the error in the post

Comment: but you are using `src: '../assets/background.mp4'` at your `renderer.js`

Comment: your electron version?

Comment: Yeah i've corrected this, it's not working too

Comment: I'm using the latest version off electron 8.2.5

Comment: Is this also broken in a standard browser? Or does this only happen inside Electron?

Comment: No its broken only in electron

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the path in the video tag itself

```
<video src="./assets/background.mp4" muted autoplay loop>
</video>
```